# Converting html table to mat table (angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I currently have a HTML table, that is populated row by row from local storage using a for loop. I was wondering if anyone is able to help me get this working as an Angular Material table. I have tried all the suggestions and code people have recommended on forums & have had no success.

The only pages this components this works with in my example is the add & list component.

[Here is a link to my stackblitz project.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hsddjeremymartorana-fkazmx)

Comment: Can you point out which modules/classes are concerned? Also try to paste a relevant minimal code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you already have installed angular material in your project.

step 1 :- create interface for you data.

```
export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}
```

step 2 :- then in you component you will have to add this.

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
dataSource: PeriodicElement[] = [];
```

displayedColumns represents columns name.
step 3 :- then in you oninit method you can assign data to dataSource variable.

```
this.dataSource = [
    {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
    {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
    {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
    {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
    {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
    {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
    {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
    {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
    {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
    {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
];
```

stpe 4 :- And in html you can display it like that.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
        The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Symbol Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

Let me know if you still have doubts.

**Updated Code**

in list.component.ts

add these two variables.

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['ID', 'Product Name', 'Manufacturer', 'Audit Interval', 'Action Buttons'];
dataSource = [];
```

then in ngOnInit add this.

```
this.dataSource = this.people;
```

Then in list.component.html

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
        The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

  <!-- ID Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="ID">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 1 </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Product Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="Product Name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Product Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.fName}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Manufacturer Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="Manufacturer">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Manufacturer </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.lName}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Audit Interval Column-->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="Audit Interval">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Audit Interval </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.aDays}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Action Column-->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="Action Buttons">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Action Buttons </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <button mat-button mat-raised-button color="accent" [routerLink]="['/edit', i]">edit  </button> 
     <button mat-button mat-raised-button color="warn"  (click) = openDialog(i) > delete  </button>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

After code update I am able to render table, please check attached screenshot.

[image]
currently ID is not coming in your data, you can use current index as ID.
Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for responding! I tried to do this one but I had trouble trying to populate data source with the values from local storage as it isn’t a static table and can be updated. Any ideas on how I can modify it to do that?

Comment: i have updated data..check does that solve your problem or not.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help this worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

The material documentation is quite clear but can always support you in the following example: https://stackblitz.com/angular/xamenaxmandm?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-http-example.ts